# Getting the number of times an item appears in an array before getting the unique values in React Code not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this my project, I have an array of objects where I'm to get the unique values so i can use the unique values as a checkbox label. Now, that works fine but the problem now is that I needed to get the numbers of occurrence in front of the values. I can't get this at the moment because the values now returns only the unique values using the Set method. Form example.. I want to have something like 2021-10-25(3) 2021-10-18(1) 2021-10-04(2).

link to replit [replitlink](https://replit.com/join/pukizlqjht-femitosin1)

Here is my App.js code

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
 
 const Defaultdata = [
  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    id: "7857699961",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-11-14",
    distance: "22.8 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:36:54",
    watched: "yes"
  },
  {
    date_listed: "3 days ago",
    id: "8358962006",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-18 - 2021-10-24",
    distance: "4.3 km",

    time_stamp: "2021-10-22 16:54:12"
  },
  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    delivery_id: "8146462294",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25",
    distance: "4.3 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32"
  },
  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    delivery_id: "8146462294",
     delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-04 - 2021-11-14",
    distance: "4.3 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32"
  },

  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    delivery_id: "8146462294",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-10-31",
    distance: "4.3 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32"
  },

  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    delivery_id: "8146462294",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-04 - 2021-11-14",
    distance: "4.3 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32"
  }
];

  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      {[
        ...new Set(Defaultdata.map((a) => a.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10)))
      ].map((dates, i) => (
        <label style={{ listStyle: "none" }} key={i}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={dates}
          />
          <span>{dates}({dates.length})</span>
        </label>
      ))}
  
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a hook `useFilteredValuesAndCounts` which will return an object that contain `dataSet` and `countObj`.

**1)** `dataSet` will contain unique dates

**2)** `countObj` is an object which contain `occurrence` of each date

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
function useFilteredValuesAndCounts(arr) {
  const countObj = {};
  const set = new Set();

  arr.forEach((a) => {
    const date = a.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10);
    countObj[date] = (countObj[date] ?? 0) + 1;
    set.add(date);
  });

  return { dataSet: [...set], countObj };
}

export default useFilteredValuesAndCounts;
```

and in JSX you can simply use as:

```
const { dataSet, countObj } = useFilteredValuesAndCounts(Defaultdata);

return (
  <div className="App">
    {dataSet.map((dates, i) => (
      <label style={{ listStyle: "none" }} key={i}>
        <input type="checkbox" value={dates} />
        <span>
          {dates}({countObj[dates]})
        </span>
      </label>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```